# delete rows in a dataframe untill it finds a certain value with python

Tags: python, drop

So I need this little piece of code to keep dropping rows until the A1 cell is a specific string, I tried this:

```
while table[0][0] != 'Nº TAD':
    table = table.drop(table.index[0])
```

but it seems the loop keeps going for more than I want and I have no idea why

Comment: What is table? a dataframe?

Comment: yes it is a dataframe

Comment: can you provide an example of the df?

Comment: well yes, it is gigantic but the first rows which are the ones I want to get rid off are 4 empty rows then 2 random strings and then the table starts with every column having a title and a bunch of numbers bellow it, i'm not sure if this is enough of an explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can itereate over rows like this:

```
for index, row in table.iterrows():
   if row["col_name"] == 'Nº TAD':
        break
   table.drop([index],inplace=True)
```

Comment: thanks man it worked! only thing for anyone that might be looking for this answer in the future it should be iterrows instead of iterows

Answer (score 0):

This does what you want. Just exchange the if-check with the `string` you want to check for. `df` is your `DataFrame`.

```
In[16]: df
Out[16]: 
   0  1  2  3
0  1  2  3  4
1  1  2  3  4
2  1  2  3  4
3  5  6  7  8

In[17]: new_df = df
   ...: for num, row in enumerate(df.values):
   ...:     if row[0] == 5:
   ...:         break
   ...:     else:
   ...:         new_df = new_df.drop(num)
   ...:   
  
In[18]: new_df
Out[18]: 
   0  1  2  3
3  5  6  7  8
```